# Converting an int array into a string array with leading zeros

Tags: java

I have an int array that I am attempting to convert to a string array then add leading zeros, however I am getting errors in my IDE and I do not understand why, any help would be appreciated.

```
    int[] dos = new int[size];
```

...adding values to dos...

```
    String intTemp[] = new String[dos.length];
    String delivery[] = new String[dos.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < intTemp.length; j++)
    {
        intTemp[j] =  Integer.toString(dos[j]);
        delivery[j] = String.format("%04d", intTemp[j]);
    }
```

Comment: And the error you get is...?

Comment: Please post the complete code (full class in this case, I guess) and the error you get. Until this, it is hard/almost impossible to answer the question.

Comment: `String[] strArray = Arrays.stream(dos).mapToObj(e -> String.format("%04d", e)).toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: intTemp[j] is a String, not an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close but I think you are doing one step too many.

```
 intTemp[j] =  Integer.toString(dos[j]);
```

is not needed as the `String.format()` will do the conversion for you:

```
String intTemp[] = new String[dos.length];
String delivery[] = new String[dos.length];
for (int j = 0; j < intTemp.length; j++) {
    delivery[j] = String.format("%04d", dos[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the `int` to `String` here:

```
intTemp[j] =  Integer.toString(dos[j]);
```

and then try to convert that string as a number here:

```
delivery[j] = String.format("%04d", intTemp[j]);
```

You should remove these two lines and replace them with:

```
delivery[j] = String.format("%04d", dos[j]);
```

And remove the `intTemp[]` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line

```
delivery[j] = String.format("%04d", intTemp[j]);
```

You try to add leading zeros to a string value. Change it with the int value

```
delivery[j] = String.format("%04d", dos[j]);
```